# What does "Strong agrees, saying" mean in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

[image]

is "Strong" a verb or a persons name? what does "Strong agrees, saying" mean?

Comment: [*strong*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/strong) isn't a verb. *agree* is a verb, so *strong* has to be a noun (the subject). The only possibility then is that "Strong" is a name. Besides, words don't talk ("saying"), people do.

Answer (score 5):

Strong is a person's last name. Most likely, the person's full name was used previously in the article. So, to save space, a writer will often shorten it to the person's last name. In this case, the writer is quoting Mr. or Mrs. Strong, and that he or she agrees with the previous quote.

Comment: It's Mark Strong, and [here's the source](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/what-to-do-your-first-day-of-work-2014-12#1-prepare-and-ask-questions-1) (warning, it's popup/ad hell).